# Aligning text in a list (with an optional prefix in the first line)

Tags: lists, alignment

I have a list, where each item can consist of one or more paragraphs. In addition, the paragraphs can be optionally marked with an extra symbol. I would like the text to align, regardless of whether they are marked or not. E.g. I have the following code

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item is not marked. 
\item \mark{*} Second item is marked and is also
multiple lines long. 
\item Third item is not marked
\end{enumerate}
```

and I want the following output:

```
1.   First item is not marked. 

2. * Second item is marked and is also
     multiple lines long. 

3.   Third item is not marked

... etc
```

I cannot use the usual tools like boxes or tables since the content is long and should properly work with page breaks etc. I also would like to avoid relying on any extra packages (the output is generated by a tool that hooks into a larger infrastructure, I don't have easy access to the main preamble). But I don't mind if the output is verbose or complex as it won't be maintained by humans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change `\mark{*}` with `\mbox{}\llap{*}`. But you probably also want to increase the distance from the numbers to the text in the itemization. One way to do this is to use the `enumitem` package.

Here is a small example (without the extra text in the screenshot):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=1em]
\item First item is not marked. 
\item\mbox{}\llap{*}Second item is marked and is also
multiple lines long. 
\item Third item is not marked
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: an item with a star]

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Took me some time to figure out the various parameters of the \list environment (since I can't use enumitem) but I got it in the end.